# Verifying the Tokens (WSE method) in WCF

Tags: wcf, security, wse

My current method to verify the username and password (Tokens) in WSE is as follows:

```
public override void VerifyToken(SecurityToken token1)
{
    if (token1 is UsernameToken)
    {
        string u1 = (token1 as UsernameToken).Username;
        string p1 = (token1 as UsernameToken).Password;

        // see if this user is already authenticated
        UsernameToken token2 = TokenCache[u1] as UsernameToken;
        if ((token2 != null) && token2.IsCurrent && (token2.Password == p1))
        {
            // less than 30s?
            if ((DateTime.Now - token2.Created) < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
                return;
            else
                // no - remove from cache
                RemoveFromCache(token1);
        }

        // not cached, so actually check
        // NB Two or more requests for same user at about same time may all fail test above
        // and thus all will call ValidateUser.  But then they will all call CacheSecurityToken below,
        // which is OK - the last one wins.
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(u1, p1))
        {
            Cache(token1);
            return;
        }

        // not authenticated
        throw new Exception("Authentication failed for " + u1);
    }
```

Any idea how can I make changes in WCF? I Have used **Microsoft.Web.Service3** WSE assembly - don't want to use that. Want to get rid of UsernameToken from my entire solution.

Comment: What are your actual requirements? Do you need to retain the same versions of the authentication protocols, or can you use the final, up-to-date versions? Many of the WSE protocols were interim versions while the standards were developed.

Comment: @John : My Requirement is simple. We have a web application which was developed using WSE (.NET 2) then we changed it to .Net 3.5 but we use the same WSE service. Now we want to upgrade the application to WCF and .net 4. 

Basically we want to keep the tunnel logic same as which we are using but would like to chase the web service logic at client end and server end. 

The above method is in security layer that verify the user when they try to login to the web app.

Hope i have given you sufficient info to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed verify my security credentials on each webservice call. I have used Directory key-value pair to cache the credentials - if anyone looking for the similar, it would help.

```
public class SecurityManager : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    //cacheCredentials stores username and password
    static Dictionary<string, string> cacheCredentials = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    //cacheTimes stores username and time that username added to dictionary.
    static Dictionary<string, DateTime> cacheTimes = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();

    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (userName == null || password == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        if (cacheCredentials.ContainsKey(userName))
        {
            if ((cacheCredentials[userName] == password) && ((DateTime.Now - cacheTimes[userName]) < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)))// &&  timespan < 30 sec - TODO
                return;

            cacheCredentials.Remove(userName);
            cacheTimes.Remove(userName);
        }
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password))
        {
            //cache usename(key) and password(value)
            cacheCredentials.Add(userName, password);
            //cache username(key), time that username added to dictionary 
            cacheTimes.Add(userName, DateTime.Now);
            return;
        }
        throw new FaultException("Authentication failed for the user");       
    }
}
```